# Will my team have to connect to ODBC if the Excel tool that's connected to Azure is saved on OneDrive?

Tags: mysql, excel, azure, odbc, azure-sql-database

I am hosting an Excel tool on OneDrive and sharing it with my team. I want to lock it up as a read only to ensure my team can’t delete it. They would need to download a new file locally every time they wanted to use the Excel tool. This Excel tool would be pulling data from Azure.

Would they need to connect to ODBC every time they wanted to use the Excel tool they downloaded from OneDrive or would it already be connected to the Azure database?

Comment: Since you want the users to just use the file in read only mode, do you mean you will be manually managing the data refresh from SQL? or you want users to be able to do that. If first, then connection to sql db will be made only when you hit refresh on the excel sheet and not when it is opened.

Comment: I would want it to be "read only" mode when it's saved on one drive (I don't want them to be able to delete or muck with the excel tool). For them to get it out of "read only" mode, I want them to save a local file to their computer. I would like users to be able to refresh the data base when ever they download the excel tool. So the latter.

Answer (score 1):

From your comments, if all you want is the Excel file to be read-only but not necessarily the data then you should use Excel to protect the sensitive sheets and restrict delete privileges on OneDrive.

You might want to consider Office 365 in lieu of OneDrive as it will have more security controls you can employ over the access controls on the file.

Here is an article about how to setup Excel to consume the Azure SQL DB directly:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1816.connect-microsoft-excel-to-windows-azure-sql-database.aspx

Comment: Would my team have to connect to ODBC every time they opened it on office 365 or would it already be connected?

Comment: Either place, the connection information should be stored in the Excel file. As long as you protect the Excel file then your users won't be able to change those settings but this is more of an Excel problem then a Azure SQL DB problem. You of course should not use a System DSN, that is a good way to ensure the database connection is setup on the user's local machine, which it sounds like is not what you want. I've updated my answer to include a link to setting up Azure SQL DB as a data source.